# Alt: getState() doesn't return class instance

Tags: reactjs, alt

I try to return class instance in Alt Store, but it always returns just Javascript Object, not class instance. Is this the default behavior of getState()? How to return class instance?

```
import alt from '../alt';
import ScheduleActions from '../actions/ScheduleActions.js';
import ScheduleApiUtils from '../utils/ScheduleApiUtils';

class ScheduleStore {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      test: new String("test")
    }
    console.log(this.state.test instanceof String); // return true
  }
  static getSchedules() {
    console.log(this.getState().test instanceof String); // return false
  }

}

export default alt.createStore(ScheduleStore, 'ScheduleStore');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to React. This is how javascript operates. Try to open console and ask the types:

```
typeof "test"
typeof {}
typeof []
typeof true
typeof false
```

If you want to check for types in javascript you might want to look at http://javascript.info/tutorial/type-detection

Comment: He's using `instanceof` not `typeof`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in JavaScript a string literal primitive and the `String` class are not the same type. In other words, a string literal is not an instance of a `String`:

```
console.log("test" instanceof String) // false
console.log(new String("test") instanceof String) // true
```

Secondly, from the Alt documentation on [`Store#getState()`](http://alt.js.org/docs/stores/) it returns a *copy* of your data:

> Once [`getState`] is called it performs a shallow copy of your store’s state,
>   this is so you don’t accidentally overwrite/mutate any of your store’s
>   state.

I don't know exactly how Alt makes this copy internally, but I assume it's not using `new String()` to copy the string values, and however it does perform the copy is converting them to string literal types.

Using `new String()` instead a string literal is not a very common practice in JavaScript.